# Ошибки при переустановке python на linux

Tags: linux

При переустановке python на более новую версию возникла ошибка:

```
chmod:  невозможно получить доступ к '/etc/audit/rules.d/astra-syslog.rules' : Нет такого файла
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета syslog-ng-mod-astra (--configure):
  installed syslog-ng-mod-astra package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
  syslog-ng-mod-astra
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?
Пробовал через apt-get -f Install, но ничего не вышло

В самом пакете syslog-ng-mod-astra есть неудовлетворительные зависимости, думаю, дело в них, но не знаю, что с ними делать
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: "При переустановке python на более новую версию" - не нужно трогать системный python вообще. Если нужна более новая версия, установите ее отдельно, а не заменяйте ту версию, которая поставляется с системой.

Comment: Это я уже понял что с ошибкой можно сделать? Вы случайно не знаете?

Comment: Проще всего - откатить обратно, например, если есть Timeshift и точка сохранения до экспериментов. А так - смотреть конкретные ошибки и пытаться их исправить. Можно попробовать вернуть старую версию Python.

Comment: Откатить возможности нет, к сожалению, старая версия не встаёт из-за этой ошибки, может есть иной способ решения проблемы?

Comment: Добавьте точный текст ошибок, текст где выводится, что есть неудовлетворенные зависимости, в общем максимально полную информацию в вопрос. Также желательно добавить вариант и версию linux. Я не специалист по починке сломанного линукса, но возможно кто-то другой что-то сможет подсказать.

Comment: Для начала попробовать удалить сломанные пакеты через `dpkg` с `force` опциями. Если это не поможет, то можно удалить/переместить `pre/post` скрипты из `/var/lib/dpkg/info` для проблемного пакета. Для ошибки в ОП: удалить файл `/var/lib/dpkg/info/syslog-ng-mod-astra.postinst`, потом попытаться удалить пакет через `apt`. Надо понимать, что все действия в обход пакетного менеджера могут привести к проблемам.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!